# Qooxdoo and Javascript - Table(Model) - Hide Table Cell?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

can't find a way to Hide a Table Cell in my Qooxdoo Table. Does anyone know a possibility?

this.getTableObj().getTableModel()...

..and then I think it has to be like..

... .getTableCell(TableRow, TableColumn).cellrenderer.Replace(null);

or maybe just like .getTableCell(TableRow, TableColumn).hideCell(); would be perfect.

EDIT: I need this functionality for showing a pressable button in a cell (just a picture). I can hide the renderer (the picture itself) but not the onclick event on the cell. this for, i would need some kind of ..cell.isVisible(false);

Thanx in advance,

best regards,
Stephan

Answer (score 0):

You should use a special table model for that. qooxdoo offers a filtered table model [1] which is exactly for that purpose. There is also a demo in the demobrowser [2] where you can take a look how it is used.

1. http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.table.model.Filtered
2. http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/demobrowser/#table~Table_Filtered_Model.html

Comment: I knew the filter before, but this is only for single rows. Not for a single cell! Isn't that right?